# House breathing through the chimney

Tags: hvac, fireplace, chimney, spray-foam

I had the attic spray-foamed and absolutely love it.  An unfortunate side-effect is that now whenever we have a fire in our fireplace (wood burning), after the fire goes out, the house fills with an ash'y/smokey smell.  We had fires for 20 years and didn't have this problem until we spray-foamed the attic.

As best as I can tell, the breathing dynamics changed by sealing the attic.  I certainly expected less flow of air (and temperature) through the attic, but didn't take into account how this might affect the HVAC's ability to breathe.

The result is that now we no longer build fires.  Which is a bummer we'd like to solve for.

I'm not sure where to start looking, or even what a solution might be called.  Maybe a pressure breather or something where the HVAC would pull air through a "relief valve intake" of some sort?

And... if that's the case, where would I put it?  The main HVAC unit is in the garage, so I wouldn't want to put an intake there.  My guess is that to balance the airflow, it would need to pull outside air from somewhere... but where?  The garage is below grade.

I hope this makes sense.  If not, please comment and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: The chimney must be pulling in replacement air, so where is air leaving the house?  Windows, doors, ceiling light fixtures, and the rim joist are common places.  You could crack open a window near the fireplace when having a fire.

Comment: The issue isn't when the fire is burning.  It's only after the fire has gone out and cooled down.  The problem only seems to happen when the HVAC runs, so my guess is the HVAC is pulling a vacuum and its drawing from the largest, easiest hole in the house -- the chimney.

Comment: Do you have a closeable damper at the bottom of the chimney?

Comment: As I understand it these "sealed attics" must have some flow of air from the conditioned space into the attic space. Originally this was supplied by leakage in the ductwork, but as ductwork became better sealed this transfer was accomplished with an actual duct outlet into the attic. Do you have that? I think there must also have been a return into the conditioned space from the attic.

Comment: Each finished floor of the house has its own HVAC system.  There are vents and returns in every room -- except the bathrooms, vents only in those.  Only the exterior surfaces of the attic are spray-foamed.  The floor/ceiling joists between the top floor and the attic still have the original batt insulation since the attic was floored.  No "open" vent from the attic to the conditioned space.  My impressions is that its actually the main floor HVAC drawing the air rather than the upstairs HVAC. There are doors closing off the upstairs from the main floor where the fireplace is.